# React alternative components definition syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am the kind of person that do not see positively the "class" keyword in the Javascript language as I feel that it does not fit well with the underlying object model. To create objects, I also prefer factories over "new" and constructor functions.

Besides, I really like React. So I have come up with a way of defining components that completely avoids the whole "class" and "extends" thing and only uses functional components or component factories. It also completely avoids to have to bind class methods or to use tricky class properties defined as arrow functions (for event handlers defined as class methods).

Before describing it, here is my question: *is it future-proof to use this syntax, or will React one day force me to use a syntax that I do not approve?*

Here is how I define components depending on the needs :

Components that only depend on their props are written as functional components (function that returns JSX):

```
const Comp = (props) => (
  <p> Hey { props.name } </p>
);
Comp.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Components for which one wants to use lifecycle hooks but that do not maintain any state are written as a function that creates and returns an object whose members are the props, the needed lifecycle methods and the render method:

```
const Comp = (props) => ({
  props,

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.doSomething();
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <p> Hey { this.props.name } </p>
    );
  }
});
Comp.propTypes = {
  doSomething: PropTypes.function.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Components that need to maintain state are written as a function that creates and returns an object whose prototype is React.Component (to gain the setState function) and whose members are the props, the state, the needed lifecycle methods and the render method. Functions called by the interface are defined in this factory function closure and act on the component (mainly setState) directly using the component instance (no binding problem here):

```
const Comp = (props) => {
  const comp = Object.create(React.Component.prototype);

  const handleClick = () => {
    comp.setState((prevState) => ({ value: prevState.value + 1 }));
  };

  return Object.assign(comp, {
    props,

    state: { value: 4 },

    componentWillUpdate() {},

    render() {
      return (
        <p> Hey { this.props.name } </p>
        <p> Value: { this.state.value } </p>
        <button onClick={ handleClick }> Increment </button>
      );
    }
  });
};
Comp.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Comment: Curios, what are some advantages to this approach vs a class component? Is performance better or worse? How does dom diffing work with these components? I would argue that it is less readable and would be harder for other React developers on the project to understand what is going on.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are bothered by this. You are getting stuck on basically meaningless things. The convention is to use `class App extends React.Component {` for components with a state and/or life-cycle methods. This is the convention and even the developers do that. Don't reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: I mainly do not like the fact that when event handlers are defined as methods of the component class, they have to be binded to the component in the constructor so that the "this" context points to the component when called. I understand why it is needed, but it does not feel right to me. I know workarounds like doing `onClick = { () => this.handleClick(); }`, but I find it unintuitive why you would have to do that. I find that defining event handlers outside of the component (here in the component factory context) while having access to the component instance makes everything more explicit.

Comment: Maybe the experimental class properties with arrow functions is the most acceptable way to solve this problem when using class components. But it still feels tricky..